# How do I summon a particle in relation to where a mob is facing?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So i am making a backrooms map and i wanted to make custom wither skeletons with particles. I wanted to summon the soul speed particle (Minecraft:soul_particle) on there shoulders and when i tried using `/execute at @e[type=wither_skeleton] run /particle Minecraft:soul_particle ~.5~1~` it would spawn on the skeletons shoulder but if it moved the particle would stay on the ~.5x coordinate from the skeleton rather than staying on his shoulder. How can i make it so that it would stay on his shoulder instead of staying in a specific cordinate from the center of the mob?

Comment: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Coordinates#Local_coordinates

Comment: Yo thx man. That helped a lot.